# Unable to increase the width of ng2-autocomplete by keeping the input text width same

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm trying to increase the width of the auto-complete dropdown keeping the text both width constant.
When I tried to click on the autocomplete by opening the inspect element debugger in chrome the dropdown gets vanished if I try to figure out the classes/elements.Is there any way to keep the dropdown opened so that I can change the look and feel of the dropdown by overriding classes.

I also tried making element state in chrome to `:active` and  `:focus`

Somehow by reading through one of the [issues](https://github.com/ng2-ui/auto-complete/issues/187) I figured out the classes  and tried to apply but not reflecting.

```
 <style>
   ng2-auto-complete ul li {
   color:blue;
   width:150%;
}
    </style>
```

Plunker link [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mzpqicqi82rI3mTYSAm3?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently missing the dot or hash before the ng2-auto-complete class. You need a dot if it's a class or a hash if it's an ID.

```
 <style>
   .ng2-auto-complete ul li {
   color:blue;
   width:150%;
   }
    </style>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @TidyDev Is there any way to keep the auto-complete  open to debug/apply classes .I'm losing the control as soon as I click out of the page/anywhere else

Comment: Since `ng2-auto-complete` is an element I think dot is not required.What's your opinion?

Comment: You're correct, it's used as both an element name and a class name. Does the ng2-auto-complete element have any inline css that specifies the width? This may be overriding your css code elsewhere.

Comment: Not sure.That's what the problem.When I try to inspect element the dropdown it fades away as I click outside the dropdown.Not able to inspect the class

Comment: app/app.component.ts is specifying:                styles: [`
    ng2-auto-complete, input {
      display: block; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 300px;
    }
  `]
})          That's where the width is being set to 300px.

Comment: I think my problem is not clear.I want to inspect the dropdown in chrome and modify css in the debugger which I'm not able to do as the dropdown closes automatically.

Comment: @forgottofly inspect the input box, then with the dev tools still open type some text into the input box. This will show you the code for ng2-auto-complete. I was able to do this and it's how I was able to find where the width was being set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155701/discussion-between-forgottofly-and-tidydev).